# Cделать импорт любых файлов для любых браузеров через js

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с такой проблемой - не могу в `html` документ импортировать `txt` , `html` , `php` файлы, а пару лет назад работало все. А сейчас только некоторые браузеры поддерживают.
Нет ли способа делать импорт через `js` - нужные участки кода,текста(их может быть много) в определенный `div` в `html` странице?

Хочу как можно больше облегчить основной документ `html`).

Comment: я ничего не понял

Comment: простите, например в сайте есть большой текст, а сам он написан в txt документе , а не в самом html файле. И таких файлов txt html и php много. Как можно их подключить чисто через js к html основному

Comment: я так понял вы html-ку даблкликом открываете?

Comment: Понятнее не стало. Как вы себе представляете подключение php через js на html?

Comment: неочень понял- у меня опен сервер на компе и запускаю файл сайта через меню этого эмулятора. html главный файл сайта.

Comment: ну обычный способ чтот неработает у меня - раньше спокойно подключал php внутрь html , а сейчас уже неработает.

Comment: чтот нашел в инете, но неуверен еще что это мне подойдет).https://webpack.js.org/

Comment: У вас небольшой сумбур в голове, мне кажется. Почитайте вдумчиво, что такое php, html и js. После этого, надеюсь, вы поймете что и как надо делать.